# How can I keep a mistyped URL in the address bar while still showing a not found page to the users?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Here is an example of what I am looking for: https://www.sitepoint.com/dhbfh/

If you visit the above link, you don't get redirected to a not found page. The original URL in the address bar remains unchanged but the page content still shows a not found message. How can I do that?

Currently, I am using the following line in my `.htaccess` and nothing else.

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mywebsite.com/not-found.php
```

Do I need to remove this line or do I need to do something else to implement a not found like the SitePoint example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example url uses url-rewriting in the `.htaccess` file. You can send all urls that do not correspond to an existing file to your error document:

```
RewriteEngine On

#if the request is an existing file, show the file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#else show your 404 page
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /not-found.php [QSA,L]
```

Also, make sure that the `not-found.php` page sends the correct 404 header:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```